# Solving a function with root

Tags: functions

I am trying to solve this function, the answer must be 2 but I can't seem to understand how to get it.

$$\sqrt{-3x + 6} = 0$$

[Work I've done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztr9V.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt{-3x + 6} - 6 = 6$ instead of $\sqrt{-3x} = -6$ ?

Comment: $\sqrt{-3x+6}\neq \sqrt{-3x}+6$

Comment: Oh no, I see what you have done. Your method is completely wrong, sorry but you need to visit the rules for solving equation again. Khan academy is a good place to start.

Comment: You can solve a problem or an equation, but not a function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the step you've done incorrectly. Note that the $+6$ is inside a square root, so you cannot subtract $6$ on both sides as you've done.
$$\sqrt{-3x+6}=0 \not\Rightarrow \sqrt{-3x}=-6$$
A correct approach would be to square both sides:
$$(\sqrt{-3x+6})^2=0^2 \implies -3x+6=0$$
Can you continue?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not correct,usual procedure when dealing with such equations is

- The first step is to *define* the square root which means that
  everything under square root must be $\geq 0$ in this case $-3x+6\geq
     0$
- The second step would be to square both sides,before squaring check if both sides are non-negative; for example $\sqrt{-3x+6}=-1$ would be impossible becasue squareroot is always $\geq0$
- The third step could be to check whether the solutions you've got are actual solutions to the first equation,you can do this by checking the conditions or by directly plugging in the solutions you've got.

Now here are some mistakes you made
$$\sqrt{-3x+6}\neq \sqrt{-3x}+6\\\sqrt{-3x}\neq -\sqrt{3x}\\\sqrt{3x}=\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{x}\neq 3\sqrt{x}$$